# WCF raises exceptions when run from IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, iis

I developed an `ASP.NET` Website that uses the `ServiceModel` classes to communicate between a C# project. I followed this example:

https://dopeydev.com/wcf-interprocess-communication/

when using `IIS Express` within VisualStudio all works fine.
Now, I moved the web site to `IIS`. When the user from the web page submits a form, the code-behind will use `WCF` to send the data to the C# application.

At this moment an exception is raised:

[image]

Debugging it will lead to the following error message:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.FatalException'
>   occurred in System.ServiceModel.Internals.dll
>
> Additional information: An asynchronous operation cannot be started at
>   this time. Asynchronous operations may only be started within an
>   asynchronous handler or module or during certain events in the Page
>   lifecycle. If this exception occurred while executing a Page, ensure
>   that the Page is marked <%@ Page Async="true" %>. This exception may
>   also indicate an attempt to call an "async void" method, which is
>   generally unsupported within ASP.NET request processing. Instead, the
>   asynchronous method should return a Task, and the caller should await
>   it.

My page already has the `Async="true"` mark and I searched across the entire solution and I have no "async void" keywords.

How to get it working also in IIS?

Answer (score 1):

I forgot to enable the `Windows Communication Foundation HTTP Activation` in the Windows Features.

Comment: Actually it worked ONCE. Now the messages aren't received anymore.